# How to evaluate the java operators evaluation

Tags: java, operators

I am java newbie and trying to understand how calculation steps are performed to achieve final result. The final answer is coming as 49. Looking at precedence operators hierarchy my calculation is not coming to 49.

Following is my code with expression:

```
class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   int a = 6, b = 5;
   a = a + a++ % b++ *a + b++ * --b;
   System.out.print(a)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo has same precedence as division and multiplication. The next precedence goes to addition and subtraction.**Operations happen left to right.**

Adding brackets for better clarity:

```
      ( a ) + ( a++ % b++ *a ) + ( b++ * --b )
group   I         II                 III
```

1. a++ % b++ *a evaluated as :a. (6 % 5) = 1
   b. 1 * 6  till now, a = 6, b = 5

Having completed this operation, the value of a & b are incremented to 7 & 6 respectively. i.e the post fix increment happens only after the modulo/multiplication/division during a step or group as shown above.

2. b++ * --b => 6 * 6. gives value of 36
   Having completed this operation the ++ operation is performed but -- is also performed, effectively leaving the value of b at 6.
3. next operation is addition. i.e 7 + 6 + 36 = 49

Reference: https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/operator-precedence

Answer (score 0):

Operators have priorities. There is a table of these [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Also, you can use round brackets (parentheses) for forcing the right sequence of calculations.

Comment: can you share details about specific operators the poster is using , instead of just posting the link